# Asp.net Core - site getting redirected to azurewebsites.net

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an asp.net core 2.1 application hosted in azure, with a basic log in system. I am using Identity to manage accounts, and signInManager for login/logout access.

so, i got to **mysite.com** and log in, it redirects to the correct page.
if i log out, I am redirected back to the mysite.com page.

While logged in, if I go to mysite.com/controller/1, it goes to the page correctly.
If logged out and i go to /mysite.com/controller/1, instead or redirecting back to the login page at mysite.com, it redirects to **mysite.azurewebsites.net**

I am unsure if its a code issue or a azure portal configuration issue
Any help appreciated

Comment: It will be easier to help if U can show codes from the Action-Methods listed above/

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?

Comment: Hi @JasonPan . Unfortunately issue still persists. I rewrote and restructured some of my code, and pushed to a cloned app service and issue still persists. That was a couple of weeks ago, so havent looked at it any further since